# Using caller id as twilio number in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I've opened up a twilio trial account. I want to use my verified called ID number in my asp.net application instead of buying a new twilio number. But I don't know how to use it. Here are my codes,

```
public ActionResult SendSms()
    {
        string ACC_SID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACC_SID"];
        string AUTH_TKN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AUTH_TKN"];

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACC_SID, AUTH_TKN);
        client.SendMessage("+8801941234567", "+8801671234567", string.Format("This is a test message!"));
        return RedirectToAction("SmsView");
    }
```

Nothing happened with it. How can I use my called ID to send sms?

Answer (score 1):

> I faced the same scenario while I was working on Twilio first time and at that time I used below steps to make things workable.

1) First of all I would suggest please add Try{} catch{} block in your SendSMS function. this will give you idea like SendMessage worked correctly.

2) In twilio we need to register mobile no before send SMS.

3) if your function works fine(no error occur) then in Twilio there is LOG tab where you can see weather your SMS send correctly or not.

Comment: In no. 2, do you mean to verify my own mobile number or to buy a twilio number?

Comment: on this link : -https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest  It mentioned that  `If you are using a Twilio Free Trial account for this example, you will only be able to send messages to phone numbers that you have verified with Twilio. Phone numbers can be verified via your` [Twilio Account's Phone Numbers Page](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers)

Comment: In the 22nd line of code, `"YYY-YYY-YYYY", // From number, must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number`.........can I use my verified local phone number instead of Twilio number?

Comment: Yes you can. but when I verified my indian no. i didn't got SMS but when I verified US no. I got SMS. But I made sure that by Twilio LOG that my code is working fine.

Comment: There are two types of numbers, `Number` & `Friendly Number`. Which one should I put in my code?

Comment: `Number` would be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77163/discussion-between-jinesh-jain-and-sin-oscuras).

Comment: There is a `SID` for that number. Should I put this one on my `web.config` or the `SID` from my twilio dashboard is ok?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Jinesh's answer has some useful parts, like using a try/catch block to see errors.

However, the problem is that you are trying to send an SMS from your own number, not from a Twilio number. When sending SMS, you can only send from Twilio numbers. [Please see this page for details on why](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app).

You should have got a Twilio number when you signed up. Try using that number as the `From` number instead.

Comment: I also tried that. It seems the problem is Twilio doesn't support some countries like Bangladesh, India etc. What Jinesh said is, he tried on indian number and it didn't work but when he tried on US number, it worked. Same thing happened with me. It doesn't matter which number I use to send sms from my asp.net project, if the recipient's number is not supported then its a loss. Either there is some kind of problem in our operators or Twilio doesn't support in some countries.

Comment: Hi Sin, there are some different restrictions in place when sending SMS to Indian numbers, take a look at https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices for the details.